# Aggregate data per week

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to aggregate data weekly according to a date and a value.

I have a table like this :

```
create table test (t_val integer, t_date date);

insert into test values(1,'2017-02-09'),(2,'2017-02-10'),(4,'2017-02-16');
```

This is the query :

```
WITH date_range AS (
   SELECT   MIN(t_date) as start_date,
            MAX(t_date) as end_date
   FROM test
)
SELECT
    date_part('year', f.date) as date_year,
    date_part('week', f.date) as date_week,
    f.val
FROM    generate_series( (SELECT start_date FROM date_range), (SELECT end_date FROM date_range), '7 day')d
 LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT  t_val as val, t_date as date
    FROM    test
    WHERE   t_date >= (SELECT start_date FROM date_range)
        AND t_date <= (SELECT end_date FROM date_range)
    GROUP BY    t_val, t_date
) f
ON  f.date BETWEEN d.date AND (d.date + interval '7 day')
GROUP BY date_part('year', f.date),date_part('week', f.date), f.val;
```

I expect a result like this :

```
| Year | Week | Val |
| 2017 |  6   |  3  |
| 2017 |  7   |  4  |
```

BUt the query returns :

```
| Year | Week | Val |
| 2017 |  6   |  1  |
| 2017 |  6   |  2  |
| 2017 |  7   |  4  |
```

What is missing ?

Comment: Remove ` f.val` from the `group by` and use `sum(f.val)` in the select list

Comment: This sums the values for the next week : http://rextester.com/GUXMAF20915